# Concurrent modification in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, collections, java.util.concurrent

I'm rookie to the world of java.until.concurrent. Need an insight before applying ConcurrentHashMap in the code. Theoretically the map internally segments to 16 metamerics(Default Segmentation though can be customized). Each catering to different threads while processing. Now that there two or more threads trying to manipulate the content on the map... So how does the synchronization happens across other threads subsequently while it is being read.

Comment: The internal linked list per bucket is handled in a thread-safe way that doesn't make any guarantees on whether iterators see changes to it, but at least always sees a consistent view.

Answer (score 2):

The synchronization is transparent to the developer. Since `ConcurrentMap` interface extends the `java.util.Map`, you can invoke the get/put methods on `ConcurrentHashMap` as you do with `HashMap`, the JVM will handle the synchronization in background transparently. You don't need to care about it.